# Why does the navigation arrow bounce off and jerk on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Why does the right navigation arrow jerk when hovering incompletely, and for some reason moves away from the left arrow with increasing length when fully hovering? The right arrow does not behave like that, and in positioning they are almost the same

Site cn39614.tmweb.ru

Code jsfiddle.net/c8nq3krw/

```css
.spaces-gal .owl-prev i,
.spaces-gal .owl-next i {
  color: #9a9a9a;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  right: 120px;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-prev:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #9a9a9a;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-prev:hover:after {
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom-color: #ff5722;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-prev:hover i {
  color: #ff5722;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-next {
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 93%;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-next:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block !important;
  border-bottom: 6px solid #9a9a9a;
  width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-right: -20px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-next:hover:before {
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom-color: #ff5722;
}
.spaces-gal .owl-next:hover i {
  color: #ff5722;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It moves because it's hit area is small - in fact it only covers a little of the actual button - so when the hover occurs and the icon moves slightly, it moves outside of the hit area, which triggers a mouseleave. That is the shake. One solution is to set a width for that element, and adjust the left:% to compensate:

```
.spaces-gal .owl-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100px;
    left: 91%;
    width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: I did as you wrote, but she still drives off and twitches

Comment: when i make that adjustment in the console when viewing your page it mostly fixes it. Truly though- the way to 'fix' this is to have a hit area that doesn't move. Move the element inside the hit area but don't make the hit area move with the element. Otherwise, there will always be the potential for this twichyness

Comment: Do you mean to insert a block of a specific width? If yes, then you cannot do it in the Owl carousel for navigation.